# How do I translate/change the text of the order receipt email in Commerce 2?

Tags: commerce

The Commerce 2 documentation describes [how to send a an order confirmation receipt](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/orders/customer-emails):

1. Go to the Commerce admin page.
2. Choose order types.
3. Click edit for the relevant order type and check the box to email a receipt.

However, how do I translate the text of this receipt?  There appears to be no UI for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the **Subject** on the UI translate page (/admin/config/regional/translate).  Search for *Order #*.

The rest can be found in a twig template:

`/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/order/templates/commerce-order-receipt.html.twig`

Copy this template to your theme and then edit as desired.  You can also use the template as a guide for what to search for on the translation UI screen to translate everything.